# Pass data from Activity to Fragment of ViewPager via FragmentPagerAdapter

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity

How is possible to send data to from `Activity` to `Fragment`  of  `ViewPager` via `FragmentPagerAdapter`?

Thanks!

**AppCompatActivity**

```
public class UnitDetailsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  private ViewPager viewPager;

   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_unit_details);


 viewPager = (android.support.v4.view.ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.container);

  // Getting unitID  via and pass it to Fragment ???
  int unitID = getIntent().getStringExtra("SelectedUnitDeviceId");
  // And how to pass it to Fragment?      

        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {                
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            }
        });

        adapter = new ViewPagerUnitDetailsAdapter(this.getSupportFragmentManager());
        fragmentReportHauls = new FragmentReportHauls();
        fragmentReportsDowntime = new FragmentReportsDowntime();

        adapter.addFragment(fragmentReportHauls);
        adapter.addFragment(fragmentReportsDowntime);

        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

}
}
```

**FragmentPagerAdapter**

```
public class ViewPagerUnitDetailsAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerUnitDetailsAdapter (FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        if(position == 0){
            // How to pass here unitID ???
            return FragmentReportHauls.newInstance(????);
        }
        else {
            return FragmentReportsDowntime.newInstance(???);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        if(position == 0){
            return FragmentReportHauls.PAGE_TITLE;
        }
        else {
            return FragmentReportsDowntime.PAGE_TITLE;
        }
    }
}
```

**ViewPager Fragment**

```
public class FragmentReportHauls extends Fragment {

    public static final String PAGE_TITLE = "Shift";

    private final String unitID;

    public FragmentReportHauls() {
    }

    // Here I want to get unitID
    public static FragmentReportHauls newInstance(String unitID) {
        FragmentReportHauls fragment = new FragmentReportHauls();
        this.unitID = unitID;
        return fragment;
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_report_hauls, container, false); 


        return view;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: have you tried using interfaces . ?

Comment: are you want passing data on which fragment means during scroll or specific fragment? why via FragmentPagerAdapter ? for easy you can use of Interface.

Comment: You can simply pass your desire data in constructor of fragment with `Yourfragment.newInstance(String xyz)` like that or you can implement `interface` call back to send and receive data.

Comment: in view pager adapter create another constructor and pass data via constructor to it , and from view pager adapter send data to fragment via bundle setarguments

Comment: @HemantParmar I want to pass data `unitID` to both Fragment.

Comment: @Piyush Yeah... But how I can do it via Adapter? Thats why I am sharing the entire code to get help with correct changes...

Comment: @Redman Please provide code solution based on my working code. I just added extra comments.

Comment: @AcademyofProgrammer please check my code , convert the values to what ever you need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I found solution.

**AppCompatActivity**

```
public class UnitDetailsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  private ViewPager viewPager;

   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_unit_details);


 viewPager = (android.support.v4.view.ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.container);

  // Getting unitID  via and pass it to Fragment ???
  int unitID = getIntent().getStringExtra("SelectedUnitDeviceId");
  // And how to pass it to Fragment?      

        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {                
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            }
        });

        adapter = new ViewPagerUnitDetailsAdapter(this.getSupportFragmentManager());
        fragmentReportHauls = new FragmentReportHauls();
        fragmentReportsDowntime = new FragmentReportsDowntime();

        adapter.addFragment(fragmentReportHauls, unitID);
        adapter.addFragment(fragmentReportsDowntime, unitID);

        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

}
}
```

**FragmentPagerAdapter**

```
public class ViewPagerUnitDetailsAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

     private final String unitID;

    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerUnitDetailsAdapter (FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String unitID) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        this.unitID = unitID;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        if(position == 0){           
            return FragmentReportHauls.newInstance(this.unitID);
        }
        else {
            return FragmentReportsDowntime.newInstance(this.unitID);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        if(position == 0){
            return FragmentReportHauls.PAGE_TITLE;
        }
        else {
            return FragmentReportsDowntime.PAGE_TITLE;
        }
    }
}
```

**ViewPager Fragment**

```
public class FragmentReportHauls extends Fragment {

    public static final String PAGE_TITLE = "Shift";

    private final String unitID;

    public FragmentReportHauls() {
    }

    // Here I want to get unitID
    public static FragmentReportHauls newInstance(String unitID) {
        FragmentReportHauls fragment = new FragmentReportHauls();
        this.unitID = unitID;
        return fragment;
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_report_hauls, container, false); 


        return view;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is an Example where I am sending an int value from Activity to fragment via viewpager adapter

```
 public class MyJobsHistoryServiceProviderPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    int type;

public MyJobsHistoryServiceProviderPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

public MyJobsHistoryServiceProviderPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm,int type) {
    super(fm);
    this.type=type;
   }

  @Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {

    MyJobsHistoryFragment fragment = new MyJobsHistoryFragment();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putInt(Constants.POSITION, status);
    bundle.putInt(Constants.TYPE,type);
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);

    return fragment;
}
}
```

Setting ViewPager Adapter

```
pagerAdapter = new MyJobsHistoryServiceProviderPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), Constants.USER_TYPE_SERVICE_PROVIDER);
  mViewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
```

and in fragment

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    status = getArguments().getInt(Constants.POSITION, 0);
    type = getArguments().getInt(Constants.TYPE, 0);
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_myjobs_history, container, false);

}
```